# SoftLayer REST API network storage array

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

How to get a list of all network storage objects of all types (i.e. iscsi, hub, evault, nas, lockbox)?

I use the mask: mask[networkStorageCount,networkStorage[nasType,fileNetworkMountAddress]]

and i get back networkStorageCount = 4, but an empty array of networkStorage.

The following is the http request/response:

Running GET on https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account.json?objectMask=mask%5BnetworkStorageCount%2CnetworkStorage%5BnasType%2CfileNetworkMountAddress%5D%5D with no body

Got 200 on https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account.json?objectMask=mask%5BnetworkStorageCount%2CnasNetworkStorageCount%2CnetworkStorage%5BnasType%2CfileNetworkMountAddress%5D%5D with body: {"complexType":"SoftLayer_Account","accountManagedResourcesFlag":false,{...},"nasNetworkStorageCount":1,"networkStorageCount":4,"brand":{"complexType":"SoftLayer_Brand","catalogId":14,"id":2,"keyName":"SOFTLAYER_US","longName":"SoftLayer Technologies, Inc.","name":"SoftLayer USA"},"networkStorage":[]}

I also try using a normal http GET request and response is []

https://{UserId}:{API_KEY}@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the list of staorages in you account you need to call this method:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/softlayer_account/getnetworkstorage

Comment: that is exactly what I am calling, I get back an empty array.

Comment: you can verify that it is not working by using a REST client.

Comment: are you sure that you have permissions to see the storages?

Comment: it is working for me, I did not use your mask I think that is wrong, but the method is listing all the storages

Comment: ok, thanks. There may be a problem with our environment. The mask is correct if you are using a service of type Account.Service (for the java client). If it were wrong, there would be an error in the body of the response. 
What client are you using to make it work, and what type of Service?

Comment: Thanks! I tried this `https://{UserId}:{API_KEY}@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage?`  and still get back an empty array, I know for a fact there is nas type network storage on this account. I appreciate all of your help. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I think is for permissions, try to log on https://control.softlayer.com/ with the same API user that you are using for the REST request, and see if you can see the storages

Comment: you shoudl see the same results using the control.softlayer.com and the API

Comment: It may be a permissions issue. I cannot see it in the portal, but neither can my system admin who is the owner of the account. Where should it be?

Comment: Edit: It probably is a permissions issue

Comment: It was the permissions. Thanks so much @Nelson!